# How to select option on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, html-select

I am trying to write some JS code for a chrome extension to auto select a option on page load. So far I havent been able to figure it out. This is what I have --

```
document.getElementByValue("9.0").selected=true;
```

What Im trying to do is have it select the option and then click the submit button using --

```
document.getElementByClass('active_step').click();
```

This is the page Im testing on - Test Page

Ok I think Im getting close, Im using the following code --

```
function SubmitIt(){
$("input[name='pdp_addtocart']").click();
}

function SelectIt(){
document.getElementById("product_sizes").selectedIndex = 3;
}

SelectIt();
SubmitIt();
```

The select option is highlighted but it is not actually being clicked because the page is telling me to choose an option first, which Im assuming my code tried clicking submit. So now I need to figure out how to actually click the highlighted option.

Comment: You failed to tell us what doesn't work.

Comment: neither was working cause the click couldnt happen til the option was selected, but i think I got it to select it, I just dont know how to get the click to happen afterwards

Comment: My above code for the select, highlights the option but doesnt necessarily click on it, which is what I was trying to do. So there would be a option selected and clicked then the submit button clicked. @PaulDraper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some messing around with your Test Page, it turned out there is more happening in the background besides setting the selected value for the `product_sizes` `<select>` element. There is, also, a *hidden* `<input>` element that holds the actual selected value, so it's value has to be set as well (see code below):

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "offline_enabled": false,

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":    ["*://www.example.com/*"],
        "js":         ["content.js"],
        "run_at":     "document_end",
        "all_frames": false
    }]
}
```

**content.js:**

```
var selectedIdx = 3;
var selectSize = document.querySelector('select#product_sizes');
var hiddenSize = document.querySelector('input[type="hidden"]#pdp_selectedSize');
var addToCart  = document.querySelector(
        'input[type="submit"][name="pdp_addtocart"]');

if ((selectSize !== undefined) && (hiddenSize !== undefined)
        && (addToCart !== undefined)) {
    selectSize.selectedIndex = 3;
    hiddenSize.value = selectSize.value;
    addToCart.click();
}
```

**<UPDATE>**

For selecting based on size, modify **content.js** like this:

```
var targetSize = 9.0;
var selectSize = document.querySelector('select#product_sizes');
var hiddenSize = document.querySelector('input[type="hidden"]#pdp_selectedSize');
var addToCart  = document.querySelector(
        'input[type="submit"][name="pdp_addtocart"]');

if ((selectSize !== undefined) && (hiddenSize !== undefined)
        && (addToCart !== undefined)) {
    var targetSizeStr = targetSize.toFixed(1);
    var optionFound = [].slice.call(selectSize.querySelectorAll('option'))
                              .some(function(opt) {
        if (parseFloat(opt.value).toFixed(1) === targetSizeStr) {
            hiddenSize.value = opt.value;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    optionFound && addToCart.click();
}
```

**</UPDATE>**

---

<sub>**Note:** If you care about the looks of the page (i.e. not only to add the item to cart, but you want the page to look exactly the way it would look if the size was selected manually etc), there are some extra modifications you need to apply. E.g. hide the `<select>` element (`display: none;`), set the `data-content` attribute of the `<a>` element just above the `<select>` to the `<select>`'s value and its class to `size_selected`, set the *addToCart* `<a>`'s class to `active_step` and maybe more.</sub>

Comment: Ok I ran into one problem. Because the selectedindex's option values are not consistent, is there any way to do it by option value instead of select index?

Comment: Why don't you give the exact requirements from the start, please ? What is our input and what is the expected outcome ?

Comment: the requirements were met, I just didnt realize that the selectedindex that corresponds to the sizes will vary, so for example instead of 3 always corresponding to size 9, it differs. So I was asking how to choose based on option value instead of sequence of order. Besides that though your answer works great, its just the selectedindex/option value problem.

Comment: @user3089477: Did you try my updated answer ? Did it work for you ? Please, consider upvoting the answer if you find it appropriate :)